# BB10 Momentics unable to create Debug Token

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

It appears that the signing server for BB10 debug tokens is down, making it impossible to run apps on target devices. The forums on Blackberry's site have been taken down with the promise that BlackBerry developers will monitor stack overflow from now on.

Now that BlackBerry is no longer overseeing app development, would it be possible to allow developers to sign their own code? It would enable individuals to test on personal devices and BB10 users to authorize specific certificates.

BB10 is still a great platform to use and develop for. It would be nice if this obstacle was removed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are monitoring posts here now, thank you for posting.  There was an issue that was causing intermittent errors with BlackBerry Debug Token creation.  That issue has been resolved.  Let us know if you run into any further issues.

As of now there are no plans that would allow developers to bypass signing requirements on BlackBerry 10.